# Big O notation of a while loop, when index is squared each iteration

Tags: while-loop, big-o, time-complexity

I need help understanding the time complexity of this algorithm and any algorithm which iterates in such a way (i = i*i), i cannot figure out how many times this loop would execute in proportion to n: is it log n? log log n? or something similar? how can i analyze such a thing? Thanks in advance :D

```
function(n):
    i=5
    while i<n: 
    {
       do.something()
       i = i*i
    }
```

Comment: basic math: what's the inverse of i*i? there's your complexity.

Comment: @MarcB not true. the first time is `5`, then `25`, then `625` etc. how could it be `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: thanks a lot; isn't the inverse of i^2  = sqrt(i)? how did you know it was O(logn)?

Comment: @BoazYakubov sorry i was wrong. it should be `O(log log n)`.

Comment: how can you know it is so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by observing that after k repetitions of the loop the value of `i` can be computed as 5<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>.

Loop is going to stop when the value of `i` reaches `n`, so you need to rewrite the equation n=5<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> for k: log<sub>5</sub>n=2<sup>k</sup>, log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>5</sub> n) = k

Therefore, the complexity of the loop is O(log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>5</sub> n))

Comment: The constants on the log base don't matter in Big-O notation, so it's just O(log(log(n)).  This is because log(any base)(x) = log(another base)(x) / log(another base)(any base), so the denominator in that expression is a constant, and constant factors are not part of Big-O.

Comment: Thanks, This is a great explanation, (cant up vote because of reputation, but thumbs up! )

Comment: @franji1 That's true, as long as the base is above 1 (and both 2 and 5 are above 1) the expression in big-O notation is the same.

Answer (score 0):

it's not simple inverse relation.

think about it, how `i` goes up.

if it's in your `j`-th iteration, what's your current value of 5?

well, by simple math, you know you have to square 5 for j times, that is

```
(...(...(5)^2...)^2...)^2=5^(2^j)
```

so if it terminates during this iteration,

```
5^(2^j) >= n
```

so you solve `j`, you can get the expression of O-notation.